# Why Vi editor can be "time-efficient" in comparison to using Nano editor?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm working through OSCP course where I'm getting familiar with terminal-based text editors.
I'm quite comfortable with Nano and this material says that penetration testers have reported
that Vi editor saved them a great deal of time. How so ? I mean, Nano editor is so straightforward and yet Vi gets the praise.

Comment: this will probably get closed, but the gist is "shortcuts" and "functionality". You can do so much more with vi/vim

Comment: One of the first things I do after fresh install is to install `vi` and change default editor to it ...